# Clarification on Some Definition of Inner Product Space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional Real vector space and $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Suppose that $V$ has a basis $(e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_n)$ of eigenvectors of $T$, every element of $V$ can be written as a linear combination of $(e_1,\ldots, e_n)$. Thus we define an inner product of $V$ by
$$\langle a_1e_1+\cdots + a_ne_n,b_1e_1+\cdots + b_ne_n\rangle=a_1b_1+\cdots + a_nb_n$$

Verify that this is an inner product on $V$,and that $(e_1,\ldots, e_n)$ is orthonormal basis of $V$ with respect to this inner product.

---

To verify that this is an inner product, we need to show that four inner product properties hold for it. This part is easy.

My confusion is the meaning of "$(e_1,\ldots, e_n)$ is orthonormal basis of $V$ with respect to this inner product."  I don't understand the meaning of "with respect to" here. Does it imply that, with different basis will give different inner product ? How to verify that $(e_1,\ldots, e_n)$ is orthonormal basis of $V$ with respect to this inner product?

Comment: The beginning of your question is curious, because $T$ does not occur in the actual question. Since every basis is a basis of eigenvectors of _some_ linear operator (for instance of the identity operator), you might as well have started with "Let $(e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_n)$ be any basis of a real vector space $V$". The way it is fomulated now might give the impression that the inner product defined is determined by $T$, but that is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "with respect to" just means "using" (and emphasizes that whether this will not in general hold for other inner products).

To show that a basis $(e_a)$ is orthonormal, we just apply the definition, that is, we check that

$\langle e_a, e_a \rangle = 1$ for all indices $a$, and

$\langle e_a, e_b \rangle = 0$ for all indices $a, b$ such that $a \neq b$.

Comment: thx for the help. Another doubt: orthonormal basis $(e_1,...e_n)$ from the question can be obtained from any basis of $V$, for example, $(v_1,...v_n)$, by applying gram-schmidt, using the inner product as given above. This also means that $(e_1,...e_n)$ with respect to this inner product ?

Comment: Any basis becomes orthonormal this way.

Answer (score 3):

Two vectors can be orthogonal according to one inner product, but not to other. 
Example: in $\Bbb R^2$ consider:
$$\langle (x_1,y_1), (x_2, y_2)\rangle_1 = x_1x_2 + y_1y_2 \qquad \langle (x_1, y_1), ( x_2, y_2)\rangle_2 = x_1x_2 + 2 y_1y_2$$
Then $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ are $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_1-$orthogonal, but not $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_2-$orthogonal.

In general, if you have a non-degenerate (and symmetric, for avoiding technical problems) billinear form $g$, you can say that two vectors $u$ and $v$ are $g-$orthogonal if $g(u,v) = 0 $.

Comment: If we define an inner product, and given any basis of a vector space $V$,if we apply Gram-Schmidt to get the orthonormal basis. We say that it's an orthonormal basis of $V$ with respect to the inner product we defined. Is this correct understanding?

Comment: Orthogonality and orthonormality are concepts that depend on the inner product that you're working with. The book "Geometry of Minkowski Space-Time", from G.L. Naber has a part of linear algebra in which he does stuff quite generally, you might like it.